# Permutation with Repetition when r<n

Tags: permutations

Question: 
   In a game of chance after 12 rounds I have 3 wins and 9 losses. What are the possible number of sequence of outcomes after the first 5 rounds.

Approach:
   W W W and L L L L L L L L L
So total ways of arranging this in 5 rounds is 12P5 and since there is repetition divide it by 3!x9!. Obviously there is something wrong with the approach. Could someone point that out and explain

Thanks

Comment: Outcomes is sequence of wins and losses

Answer (score 0):

Five Ls $1$ way; four Ls and one W $5$ ways; three Ls and two Ws $10$ ways; two Ls and three Ws $10$ ways.   So $1+5+10+10 = 26$ ways in total.  You could write this as

$$\sum_{l=\max(0,5-3)}^{\min(5,9)} {5 \choose l}.$$

Note that the different ways are not equally probable.

Comment: Thanks Henry! Usually I use Total no. of arrangements without repetition / n1!xn2!..nk! (were n1,n2...nk is the # of repetitions). Could you tell if this is incorrect !

Comment: @user88197 - that might work if you were arranging all the items, but here you are only arranging the first few.